# XMLHttpRequest fails on SSL server using Let's Encrypt

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, xmlhttprequest, lets-encrypt

I recently updated my server from http to https using Let's Encrypt, and now I get this error on Chrome (and something along the same lines on Firefox) whenever I try to connect to a node script:

```
net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
```

This is the front end script:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();      
xhr.open("GET", SERVER+":"+PORT, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");   
xhr.send(null);
```

this is the Node script

```
https.createServer(function(req, res){         
 console.log("hi",req,res);                                                
} ).listen(PORT);
```

Now I've seen posts using  require('letsencrypt') to register security certificates, but I haven't been able to find any on my server. I don't know if it has to be created on the fly, or if it should be located in some folder. I don't know a thing about SSL, or, better put, I simply don't understand it.
Any suggestions on how to address this?

Comment: Server creation is wrong. You are not using certificates. That is not a valid https server

Comment: by the way: `xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` - you don't know CORS

Comment: Great suggestions, thanks. Any idea on how to address the issue?